# convert input string to 2 dimension array then extract it using an index file

Tags: java

Here is what I am trying to do, say I have an input file (input.txt) in this format, the number of rows or columns can be different, columns are separated by spaces:

```
the       DT   B-NP
current   JJ   I-NP
account   NN   I-NP
deficit   NN   I-NP
will      MD   B-VP << CURRENT TOKEN
narrow    VB   I-VP
to        TO   B-PP
only      RB   B-NP
```

I want to get each word into an element of a 2 dimension array x[i,j] so that, I can use an index file:

```
x[0,0]
x[0,1]
x[-1,0]
x[-2,1]
```

to get this result:

```
will
MD
deficit
NN
```

With the number in the bracket is the i,j index of the array, the starting position [0,0] is the first word of the line that marked by "<< CURRENT TOKEN" (in this case is word "will" ).

So now I can read the file to array by:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;



public class ReadfileIntoArray {

    String[] data = new String[100];

    public void read() throws IOException {


        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/home/Documents/input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        System.out.println("Print from here:");
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data[i] = line;
            System.out.println(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
        br.close();
        // This is for resize the data array (and data.length reflect new size)
        String[] dataNew = new String[i];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
        data = dataNew;
        System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadfileIntoArray rfta = new ReadfileIntoArray();
        rfta.read();
    }
}
```

But as I searched, I might need to use

```
List<String> arrList =FileUtils.readLines(new File("myfile.txt"));
```

for undefined length (??) not very sure but I think need to import special package to use it, I got error *_*
Second thing is how to determined the starting element at position [0,0], and how to indicate negative index like [-2,1]...

How can I managed to do the task above, it look quite complicated for me. Thanks alot !

Comment: Do you really have to use negative indices? That can be confusing (as well as lead to more code).

Comment: Is ` << CURRENT TOKEN` also part of text file used to indicate [0,0] position? Shouldn't be placed in array? Or maybe you want to set [0,0] manually?

Comment: Yes, it is also a part of the text file, so I guess, need to use string comparison here to know the [0,0] position. And to know the index in the bracket how do you think is the best way ? May be regular expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ArrayList of ArrayList for indefinite length.

```
public void read() throws IOException {
    List<ArrayList<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/home/Documents/input.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    int current_line = 0; 
    int cnt = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String arr[];
        arr = line.split("\t");
        mylist.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            mylist.get(cnt).add(arr[i]);
            if(mylist.get(cnt).get(i).equals("<<")) 
                current_line = cnt;
        }
        cnt++;
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Now you have arraylist of arraylist.

To get j_th element of i_th line, you should write `mylist.get(i).get(j)`

By this, you wont need to increase size of the array and also lengths of lines is not going to matter, i.e first line is 10 string and second is 15 is going to be acceptable.

Also, instead of negative indexes, keep `current_line` as a variable and for previous line, use `current_line - 1` as index.

Comment: do you mean:    mylist.get(cnt).add(arr[i]); ? If I use: mylist.get(cnt).add(i); there is error, asked to change i to String; if I use mylist.get(cnt).get(i); run will get error exception; Your suggestion for current_line I think is very bright, I can understand but actually I dont know how to implement it ...

Comment: Yes, I actually meant that. Where are you supposed to give `current_line`? Are you going to it in `main` or in `read method`, or somewhere else? If it is in read method `cnt` is `current_line`, if it is `main`, just define a variable and use that idea

Comment: I also cannot access each word by : mylist.get().get(); it will return an error about size; for example, I cant print  mylist.get(2).get(0): and result: [account   NN   I-NP]; but mylist.get(2).get(1) will return this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: The current_line should be identified by line with this string "<< CURRENT TOKEN"; it could be either in main or read method whichever easier. I don't get the idea why cnt is current line since there is no comparison to find this mark "<< CURRENT TOKEN" in the line.

Comment: Error is because you divided inputs with `space` not `tab`? If you seperate input Strings with `tab` it is going to work. Also define `currentline in main` and you will get print outs like the following. `int current_line = 4; System.out.println(rfta.mylist.get(current_line - 0).get(0));`

Comment: Also, i did a small mistake in the code above, so i editted my answer.

Comment: Yes, what you suggest is true, it works with tab, so I use this split

Comment: Yes, what you suggest is true, it works with tab, so I use this split to work with whitespace: arr = line.split("\\s+"); Two things left: the currentline is a great idea but how could I recognize the line marked ? And to get the value of i,j for mylist.get(i).get(j) from index file like U14:%x[2,1]
U15:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1]
U16:%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]; I thinking of regular expression like: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in); but it is not working for things complicated like above

Comment: use string equality for `<<` i.e. `if(mylist.get(i).get(j).equals("<<")) current_line = cnt`. For that to be true, `<<` supposed to be used only once and only at in the `current_line` as in your example.

Comment: for the string like :"U14:%x[2,1] U15:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1] U16:%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1];" I used    String pattern = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
         Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);          
         Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(linee); to get all the numbers between brackets and separated by comma (which I used later as i,j above) but System.out.println(regexMatcher.group()); return error, no result. you have any idea ?

Comment: j should run from which to which value ? I put the compare under for loop:     for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
                 mylist.get(cnt).add(arr[i]);
             if(mylist.get(cnt).get(i).equals("<<")) 
              current_line = cnt;

Comment: For the first question, it is some other question, you should search for it or ask it in another question. I editted code and put the code I said in the previous comment to the necessary position.

Comment: Great help smttsp, I step a long way ahead ! Thanks a lot !